# Create a generic channel

Tags: go

I have my struct defining a `Subscribers` that map channels.

```
package ws

type SessionHandler struct {
    Subscribers      map[chan interface{}]bool
}
```

I wanna make it possible to instantiate it with any kind of channel, like this:

```
type WsSession struct {
  handler *ws.SessionHandler
}

handler := &ws.SessionHandler{
    Subscribers:      make(map[chan WsResponse]bool),
}
```

The code example I provided doesn't work (`cannot use make(map[chan WsResponse]bool) (value of type map[chan WsResponse]bool) as map[chan interface{}]bool value in struct literal`), but how could I update it to my purposes?

Comment: The type `chan interface{}` is exactly `chan interface{}`, nothing else. If you want `chan WsResponse`, use that type instead.

Comment: @Adrian I said I wanna make it generic, right? This is just one example of how I'd use it, but I could wanna set `Subscribers` in one place like `WsResponse`, and in another place like `AnyOtherKindOfStruct`.

Comment: What is `SessionHandler` doing that it needs a channel type but doesn't care what type it is? This seems like an underlying design issue more than anything.

Comment: @rwehresmann we would need to see more of the context and structure to understand what would be a better solution. All I can tell from the code shown is that it is almost certainly not the right approach.

Comment: You can use *type parameters* in [upcoming Go 1.18](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md) the same way you would use generics or templates in various other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to accomplish will be possible in [Go v1.18](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md), as commented by @torek in my question.

For now, what I ended doing was this:

```
handler := &ws.SessionHandler{
    Subscribers:      make(map[chan json.RawMessage]bool),
}
```

I stopped relying on a go struct and communicated `json.RawMessage` in my channels. It's not totally clean because I need to marshal/unmarshal my message to give the proper treatment, but its "generic" and I could accomplish what I was trying to do.